# Call function in constructor

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to call a function when my object is created. Is there anyway to do this?

```
return declare("myObject", mySuperObject, {
    constructor: function (args) {

        test();

        lang.mixin(this, args);
    },
    test: function () {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

this results in `ReferenceError: test is not defined`

Comment: Assuming that this is some sort of "class-ish" library, just refer to `this.test()` instead of `test()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.test()` instead:

```
return declare("myObject", mySuperObject, {
    constructor: function (args) {

        this.test();

        lang.mixin(this, args);
    },
    test: function () {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect. I totally forgot to refer to `this`